# bottlenose HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: bottlenose

I'm using the code example from the [github page](https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose):

```
import bottlenose
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon('XXXX','YYYYY','ZZZZZ')
response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId='0596520999',ResponseGroup='Images',SearchIndex='Books',IdType='ISBN')
print(response)
```

And I get this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I've gathered from a lot of googling that its a certificates issue but cant figure out how to fix it (I'm a python noob).

Any ideas?

(I'm using Pycharm, python 3.6 and Lubuntu if that makes a difference)